# Mockito when().thenAnswer() not mocking future

Tags: unit-testing, flutter, dart, mockito

I have a repository class which return Future by calling another function from another class which returns same Future. And I was trying to mock the repository class using the mockito `when().thenAnswer()` function like this

```
 when(mockAccountRepository.authenticateWithEmail(
    email: email,
    password: password,
  )).thenAnswer((_) => Future.value(SignedIn(token: token)));
```

the repository class has this function that returns the Future

```
Future<AccountEvent> authenticateWithEmail({
@required String email,
@required String password,
  }) {
    return _accountApiProvider.authenticateWithEmail(
      email: email,
      password: password,
    );
  }
```

the accountApiProvider class have the bellow function which also returns same Future

```
Future<AccountEvent> authenticateWithPhone(
      {@required String phone, @required String password}) async {
    final String data = '''{"phone":"$phone","password":"$password"}''';

    try {
      final Response response = await _dio.post('url', data: data);

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print(response.data);
        final String token = response.data.accessToken;
        return SignedIn(token: token);
      } else {
        return SignInError('Internal Server Error');
      }
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      return SignInError(e.message);
    }
  }
```

So, when I run the test it doesn't return the exact mock value provided in the  `thenAnswer()` function.

Comment: What is the test code?

Comment: the code is written in Dart

Comment: I mean: you haven't provided sample test code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: Yeah. It was my fault, I was supposed to mock a repo that I didn't post here.